# Why doesn't \\(1 + 1 = 2\\) work?

Tags: support, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Math typesetting using \( \) instead of the dollars](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/math-typesetting-using-instead-of-the-dollars)

MathJAX allows putting inline math in parentheses, e.g. \(1 + 1 = 2\). But it doesn't seem to work here. Do you know why?

Comment: My guess would be that it is some sort of conflict between MathJAX and markdown to see who goes first, but I'm not sure.

Comment: To be more precise, MathJax _can be configured_ to do stuff to `\(...\)`. But here it has been configured not to.